# plot scatter with x, y title, legend based on different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I look for some code from internet and find the following function for me to plot based on third column value. like result=0 color yellow, result=1, color=purple.
But xlabel,, ylabel, title or legend do not display even I add ax.set_title, ax.set_xlabel, ax.set_ylabel, ax.legend.

how can I plot legend like "random walkers" image" "blue line" present mean population 1, "yellow line" presents men population 2
result=1, yellow
result=0, purple

```
def plot_scatter(df=tmp, xcol='freq', ycol='type', catcol='result'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    categories = np.unique(df[catcol])
    colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(categories))
    colordict = dict(zip(categories, colors))

    df["Color"] = df[catcol].apply(lambda x: colordict[x])
    ax.set_title('random walkers empirical $\mu$ and $\pm \sigma$ interval')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    ax.set_xlabel(xcol)
    ax.set_ylabel(ycol)
    ax.scatter(df[xcol], df[ycol], c=df.Color)
    return fig

fig = plot_scatter(tmp)
fig.show()
```

[image: plot result]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want here. Can you write a minimal working example and make clear what behaviour you want?

Comment: i want to have legend box like 2nd image, purple present result as 0, yellow present result as 1

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? Did you use this code to generate figure 1?

Comment: You are not calling your method `plot_scatter`. Instead, you are calling `dfScatter`, which you may have defined before. This may explain why the changes to `plot_scatter` do not have an effect.

Comment: hi, it is my typo. i am calling the correct function but still no legend as what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer:

Here's sample code that does what I think you want to do, but without a dataframe because I don't have your dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# this part should get replaced with your dataframe-based calculations
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
colordict = {0: 'yellow', 1: 'purple'}
color = list(colordict[val] for val in y)

ax.scatter(x, y, c = color, label = color)

ax.set_title('random walkers empirical $\mu$ and $\pm \sigma$ interval')
ax.set_xlabel('freq')
ax.set_ylabel('type')

# custom patches for the legend
yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow', label='population 1, result = 0')
purple_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='purple', label='population 2, result = 1')
ax.legend(handles=[yellow_patch, purple_patch])

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately my previous answer (preserved below) doesn't actually fix the problem, because I didn't understand the example I linked. What you want to do is make custom labels, which is more like [this example](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists).

As for the code in your comment, note that you need to call `legend` **after** all of the plotting commands whose labels you want included in it. I'm not sure why your axis labels and title aren't appearing - they do when I run my version.

---

The below doesn't actually solve the problem, unfortunately.

<strike>The legend isn't appearing because none of the elements in your plot have labels. You didn't provide enough code to replicate your plot, but [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) indicates that you should be able to pass `label = df.Color` to `scatter` to get the right effect. So your call to `scatter` would look like:</strike>

```
ax.scatter(df[xcol], df[ycol], c=df.Color, label = df.Color)
```

Comment: i add label into scatter, but still cannt see legend     ax.set_title('{} vs {}'.format(xcol, ycol))
    ax.set_xlabel(xcol)
    ax.set_ylabel(ycol)
    ax.plot()
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    ax.scatter(df[xcol], df[ycol], c=df.Color, label=df.Color, edgecolors='none')

Comment: @jacobcan118 I've revised my answer and included a working example.